# XPath: Selecting a node based on another nodes value

Tags: xpath, .net-4.0, xpath-2.0

I am trying to use a single XPath expression to select a node that has a child node which matches another node in the document.

A match would mean that **ALL** attributes of the node are the same.  So if a node was being compared with several attributes doing individual attribute comparisons would be unmaintainable.

**As an example** given the following:

```
<Network>
    <Machines>
        <Machine Name = "MyMachine">
            <Services>
                 <ServiceDetails Description="MyService" Executable="c:\Myservice.exe" DisplayName="My Service" Version="5"/>
            </Services>
        </Machine>
        ...
    </Machines>
    <Services>
        <Service Name = "Service1">
            <ServiceDetails Description="MyService" Executable="c:\Myservice.exe" DisplayName="My Service" Version="5"/>
        </Service>
        ...
    </Services>
</Network>
```

I want to get the service node from Services based on the ServiceDetails listed under MyMachine.

I thought it would look something like:

```
//Services/Service[ServiceDetails = //Machines/Machine[@Name='MyMachine']/ServiceDetails]
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  I suspect the '=' operator isn't handling the node comparison correctly.  I think there are some XPath 2.0 Methods that might work but I am using .NET 4.0 (System.XML namespace) I do not know if I can use them.  If XPath 2.0 methods would help here I would really appreciate an explanation on how to use them in .Net 4.0.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the `<Service>` under `<Services>` by matching the `@Description` attributes from both `<ServiceDetails>`? (This would work in that case: `/Network/Services/Service[ServiceDetails/@Description = /Network/Machines/Machine[@Name='MyMachine']/Services/ServiceDetails/@Description]` )

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
/*/Services/Service
            [ServiceDetails/@Description 
            = 
             /*/Machines/Machine[@Name = "MyMachine"]
                          /Services/ServiceDetails/@Description
            ]
```

Comment: @DevNull: Absolutely -- I saw your comment and decided to give my answer -- when I wrote it completely, I saw that it is almost identical to the expression in your comment. However, it deserves to be an answer -- not a comment. Please, create an answer with this expression, then I'll delete mine :)

Comment: I was hoping the OP would clarify the question before I answered since the XML example doesn't match the explanation of what was trying to be matched. One answer is sufficient; I will just upvote yours since I'm in agreement. :-)

Comment: Thanks -- in this case I will have a look at all your answers -- sure there will be some good one I hadn't seen before that I could upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the comparison for the question is regarding the entire node.  In the example above I would want to make sure the Description and Version were both correct. 
Given your examples I might be able to concatenate the attribute comparisons but that would quickly become unmanageable.  Is there a way to find out if the entire node matches?


However, if there are several attributes or children to this node these expressions would get extremely large rather quickly.  Is there a way to check if the nodes match rather than walk through each attribute and child?

Comment: @AAADad: You need to define what is meant by "entire nodes match". There is a term "node equality" and in XPath 2.0 there is a finction `deep-equal()`. If you need only "shallow equality" (attribute count names and corresponding values to be identical, I think this can be done with an XPath expression.

Comment: @AAADad: Also, there isn't any .NET implementation of XPath 2.0 (SQL Server XQuery implements a WD version -- not the final recommendation). You may use any existing 3rd party XSLT 2.0 or XQuery 2.0 processor. Of these, XQSharp and Saxon.NET are especially intended to be used within a .NET environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will validate all attribute values are equal in both the elements then it is true:

```
/Network[(descendant::ServiceDetails/@Description = /Network//Machine[@Name = "MyMachine"]/Services/ServiceDetails/@Description) and (descendant::ServiceDetails/@Executable = /Network//Machine[@Name = "MyMachine"]/Services/ServiceDetails/@Executable) and (descendant::ServiceDetails/@DisplayName = /Network//Machine[@Name = "MyMachine"]/Services/ServiceDetails/@DisplayName) and (descendant::ServiceDetails/@Version = /Network//Machine[@Name = "MyMachine"]/Services/ServiceDetails/@Version)]
```